# Two sets of answer choices for CrowdFlower/Mechanical Turk

Tags: survey, mechanicalturk, multiple-choice

Half the questions in my survey will have one set of multiple-choice options (call this A); the other half will have another set of multiple-choice options (call this B). How can I do this on CrowdFlower?

Should I create a column called "answer type" (specified as either A or B), then make a class in CML (CrowdFlower Markup Language) that I can grab and manipulate with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in your other question, you can use Liquid to do this without Javascript if desired. Obviously Javascript also gives you a lot of flexibility if you want to go that route.

In this case you could define an answer_type column as you described and then write:

```
{% if answer_type == "1" %}
one
{% else %}
two
{% endif %}
```

Liquid also has case statements.